# How to remove xdata entries using biber --tool_resolve --tool (after resolution)

Tags: conversion, biber

Consider the file `myrefs.bib` containing the following biblatex entries:

```
@XDATA{pom,
  EVENTDATE  = {1999-12-31/2000-01-01},
  EVENTTITLE = {Party},
  VENUE      = {Somewhere},
}

@PROCEEDINGS{pomp,
  XDATA  = {pom},
  DATE   = {2000},
  EDITOR = {Me, Myself and I},
  TITLE  = {Party-report},
}
```

I would like to convert this using

```
biber --tool_resolve -g mybiber.conf --tool myrefs.bib
```

to get

```
@PROCEEDINGS{pomp,
  EVENTDATE  = {1999-12-31/2000-01-01},
  EVENTTITLE = {Party},
  DATE       = {2000},
  EDITOR     = {Me, Myself and I},
  TITLE      = {Party-report},
  VENUE      = {Somewhere},
}
```

Can this be done? What would the corresponding map in `mybiber.conf` look like? (I know that fields can be removed using `map_null="1"`, but I haven't found such an option for entries.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a small error in your initial .bib - you need to use the `XDATA` field rather than `CROSSREF`:

```
@XDATA{pom,
  EVENTDATE  = {1999-12-31/2000-01-01},
  EVENTTITLE = {Party},
  VENUE      = {Somewhere},
}

@PROCEEDINGS{pomp,
  XDATA    = {pom},
  DATE     = {2000},
  EDITOR   = {Me, Myself and I},
  TITLE    = {Party-report},
}
```

This then gives you the "pomp" entry you want in the tool output mode. It's It's true that the original "pom" `XDATA` entry is also in the output but this is harmless as it's not referenced any more. Or is there a reason why you have to eliminate this in the output? There is a mapping option to remove entries (`map_entry_null`) but as with all mappings, this is applied on reading the data source and so it would delete an entry before any processing takes place - not what you want.

You can do a separate `biber` tool run after this to remove the resolved `XDATA` entries. Just put this in the conf file mentioned by the `-g` option:

```
<config>
  <sourcemap>
    <maps datatype="bibtex" map_overwrite="1">
      <map>
        <map_step map_type_source="XDATA" map_final="1"/>
        <map_step map_entry_null="1"/>
      </map>
    </maps>
  </sourcemap>
</config>
```

`map_entry_null` is documented in the `biber` PDF manual.

Comment: You are right of course, the `CROSSREF` field should be an `XDATA` field, I introduced this mistake while modifying the example from my real entries. I have now corrected this in the question.

Comment: Using `map_entry_null` would work (is it documented?), as I can always first do `biber --tool_resolve --tool myrefs.bib` and then `biber -g mybiber.conf --tool myrefs_bibertool.bib`.

Comment: Updated answer with a config file mapping option for removing any resolved XDATA entries in a separate `biber` run.

Comment: Thanks, and sorry about the ‘is this documented?’: it seems I have the 1.0 manual installed somehow together with version 1.6 of the program.